# LinkedIn API button automatically logs people in

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn API for login. I have that pretty little button. It works great.

However, when people "logout" of my app, something goes wrong. I do this:

1. Log the user out: `IN.User.logout();`
2. Redirect to my landing page for not logged in users: `window.location = "/index.php";`

Everything is fine, but when they get to my landing page for logged out users, where I have the log-in with LinkedIn button, they immediately get logged back in again.

**Why would they be automatically logged in again?** Didn't I just log them out? Shouldn't they need to click the *log in with LinkedIn* button again?

Here is the code for the button:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
    api_key: lydbpp0zdpad
    onLoad: LinkedInSignIn.redirect
    authorize: false
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the window.location, the browser kills all requests currently in progress. This may be preventing the logout request from going through. Can you try delaying for 5s before redirecting them? (There are ways to get around this problem without delaying, if it is indeed the issue.)

Comment: JS is single threaded, so all commands issued before the "window.location" will finish, unless they are async.

Comment: Web requests are async.

Comment: I mean if you do `var location = "myhomepage.com; window.location = location;` You will always have location be defined.

Comment: What @skishore is saying is that the logout() function is asynchronous. You call it an immediately switch pages, so the logout operation never finishes. It's easy to demonstrate this: jst inser a delay (make it long, let's say 10 seconds, to err on the safe side) between the logout and the location change, and see if it works. THEN, remove the delay, and call the page switch on logout successfully finishing.